How small coefficient of variation should be accepted for dependent variable and how does it affect linear regression?
I was wondering what happens to a linear regression model if the coefficient of variation of $Y$ variable is small. Also, what is considered as "too small CV"? What is the minimal accepted threshold?
More specific context: I am trying to build linear regression on time series data for learning purposes. There are 499 measurements of 10 numeric variables related to weather (source). Plots and numeric summary attached below.
Numeric summary table

Plots of used time series
normalized, i.e. $\frac{X- \operatorname{mean}(X)}{\operatorname{sd}(X)}$


A small CV could simply be caused by a large average and small variation. If you fit a regression, that will lead to a large intercept coefficient estimate. This model may still be worthwhile. It absolutely depends on your situation and your context. There is no minimal "accepted" CV. Can you describe your situation and your question in more detail?

This seems an example of the X-Y problem, where the name of the problem has nothing to do with customary regression notation. https://xyproblem.info/ I take it that the real question is more likely to be "Should I use linear regression?" and if so then I'd want to know much more than the CV of the outcome to give advice worth hearing. It could be for example that a large CV means that you should work with the logarithm of the outcome. Tell us more about your data. What are minimum, maximum, mean, SD, median, quartiles of the outcome? How many predictors do you have, for a start?

I've described the detail. But I still would like to try to think about it in more general context, do you think it is not possible to say something like "in most cases as a rule of thumb CV should be over 0.1 to even think about fitting linear regression model" without knowing the specific context?

Thanks for adding those details. It would help if your could also edit the question to say more about the regression analyses you have in mind. As others have noted, the coefficient of variation by itself doesn't matter for outcomes or predictors individually. As Wikipedia explains, in a simple linear regression between an outcome and a predictor, the ratio of the outcome and predictor standard deviations matters, as does the correlation between outcome and predictor.

Of the variables mentioned, the CV of wind bearing and indeed the mean are meaningless as it is a circular variable. The CV of any temperature measurement is essentially meaningless too: consider the effect of changing to Fahrenheit or kelvin to see that, although the details mix physical and statistical considerations. Which variable(s) do you consider to be outcome(s)?

@NickCox good point. "Which variable(s) do you consider to be outcome(s)?" - temperature is the outcome variable.

@EdM thanks! I totally forgot about this fact and formula. Now I think I need to read the whole wikipedia page on linear regression and come back to this question.

First, note that CV is only useful when all the values are positive.
Second, note that you can dramatically change the CV by adding a constant. This does nothing to the regression (other than the estimate of the intercept, which is usually not of interest).
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(1000, 10, 2)

y1 <- 3*x + rnorm(1000,0, 5)
y2 <- y1 + 100

sd(y1)/mean(y1)  #0.27
sd(y2)/mean(y2)  #0.061

m1 <- lm(y1~x)
summary(m1)

yields
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.31288    0.78854  -1.665   0.0962 .  
x            3.13928    0.07773  40.387   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.901 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6204,    Adjusted R-squared:   0.62 
F-statistic:  1631 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

while
m2 <- lm(y2~x)
summary(m2)

yields
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 98.68712    0.78854  125.15   <2e-16 ***
x            3.13928    0.07773   40.39   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.901 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6204,    Adjusted R-squared:   0.62 
F-statistic:  1631 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Same coefficient for x, same p, same SE etc.
Conclusion: CV is not a good method for evaluating variables for regression.
And it's not just CV.  Measures of dispersion are, in general,  not particularly good measures for evaluation the DV in a regression. It could be that you simply have a wide (or narrow) range.
One exception is known as restriction of range. But this is a different problem. It arises when the  any of the variables are not available over the entire range of interest. One place this comes up is looking at the correlation between high school grades (or other measures of academic skill in HS) and grades in college. Each college tends to take people in a certain range of HS GPA. At the extreme, you won't find many people with 2.5 HS GPA going to Yale.

Thanks, it makes it much clearer. Especially the simple fact about adding the constant changes the CV. But why you state that "CV is only useful when all the values are positive."? I don't get this part, it is a measure of dispersion and have some interpretation even if some values are negative. And also, if I shouldn't use CV for selecting "good" features for model, then what? I'm sure I've heard about using variance thresholds as a really basic form of feature selection for big datasets in ML. And this is why CV made sense initially in my head

Well, it's OK if all the values are negative, but if you have some negative and some postiive, it's useless because the mean can be arbitarily close to 0, making the CV arbitrarily large.  As for building models, there's a whole LOT of posts about that.
